# List all computers in active directory

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

Im wondering how to get a list of all computers / machines / pc from active directory?

(Trying to make this page a search engine bait, will reply myself. If someone has a better reply il accept that )

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you have a very big domain, or your domain has limits configured on how how many items can be returned per search, you might have to use paging.

```
using System.DirectoryServices;  //add to references

public static List<string> GetComputers()
{
    List<string> ComputerNames = new List<string>();

    DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://YourActiveDirectoryDomain.no");
    DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
    mySearcher.Filter = ("(objectClass=computer)");
    mySearcher.SizeLimit = int.MaxValue;
    mySearcher.PageSize = int.MaxValue;

    foreach(SearchResult resEnt in mySearcher.FindAll())
    {
        //"CN=SGSVG007DC"
        string ComputerName = resEnt.GetDirectoryEntry().Name;
        if (ComputerName.StartsWith("CN="))
            ComputerName = ComputerName.Remove(0,"CN=".Length);
        ComputerNames.Add(ComputerName);
    }

    mySearcher.Dispose();
    entry.Dispose();

    return ComputerNames;
}
```

Answer (score 16):

What EKS suggested is **correct**, but is performing a little bit **slow**.

The reason for that is the call to `GetDirectoryEntry()` on each result. This creates a `DirectoryEntry` object, which is only needed if you need to modify the active directory (AD) object. It's OK if your query would return a single object, but when listing all object in AD, this greatly degrades performance.

If you only need to query AD, its better to just use the `Properties` collection of the result object. This will improve performance of the code several times.

This is explained in [documentation for `SearchResult` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.searchresult(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Instances of the `SearchResult` class are very similar to instances of
>   `DirectoryEntry` class. The crucial difference is that the
>   `DirectoryEntry` class retrieves its information from the Active
>   Directory Domain Services hierarchy each time a new object is
>   accessed, whereas the data for `SearchResult` is already available in
>   the `SearchResultCollection`, where it gets returned from a query that
>   is performed with the `DirectorySearcher` class.

Here is an **example** on how to use the `Properties` collection:

```
public static List<string> GetComputers()
{
    List<string> computerNames = new List<string>();

    using (DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://YourActiveDirectoryDomain.no")) {
        using (DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry)) {
            mySearcher.Filter = ("(objectClass=computer)");

            // No size limit, reads all objects
            mySearcher.SizeLimit = 0;

            // Read data in pages of 250 objects. Make sure this value is below the limit configured in your AD domain (if there is a limit)
            mySearcher.PageSize = 250; 

            // Let searcher know which properties are going to be used, and only load those
            mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("name");

            foreach(SearchResult resEnt in mySearcher.FindAll())
            {
                // Note: Properties can contain multiple values.
                if (resEnt.Properties["name"].Count > 0)
                {
                    string computerName = (string)resEnt.Properties["name"][0];
                    computerNames.Add(computerName);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return computerNames;
}
```

[Documentation for `SearchResult.Properties`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.searchresult.properties(v=vs.110).aspx)

Note that properties can have multiple values, that is why we use `Properties["name"].Count` to check the number of values.

To improve things even further, use the `PropertiesToLoad` collection to let the searcher know what properties you are going to use in advance. This allows the searcher to only read the data that is actually going to be used.

> Note that the `DirectoryEntry` and `DirectorySearcher` objects should
>   be properly disposed in order to release all resources used. Its best
>   done with a `using` clause.

Comment: Nice information, however what if I want those computer objects which are in a specific organizational unit. Like Domain > MyCompany > SystemComponent > SiteLocation ?
And filter on name prefix like LAX for those items like LAX0001?

Answer (score 2):

An LDAP query like: `(objectCategory=computer)` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

if you only want to get the enabled computers:

```
(&(objectclass=computer)(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).