# Import machines from Active Directory in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, active-directory

In a Windows Forms app is there any control that allow to have a buttom to import using a from the AD DS? (something like the control that allosw to select a file)

Comment: Not sure I completely understand your question, but if you're asking if there is a control in .Net that automatically gets Active Directory information, then no, there isn't. You have to actually program that. You can use the System.DirectoryServices or System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement (.Net 3.5 and higher) namespaces and methods. Here's a [similar question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605567/list-all-computers-in-active-directory) to get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic .NET class library doesn't have anything like that, unfortunately.

But the community has been busy and provides several implementations:

- [Active Directory object picker control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6848/Active-Directory-object-picker-control)

[image]

- [Active Directory Common Dialogs .NET](http://adui.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure that it will do everything you need but it exists something called **Directory Object Picker**, it only works for users and groups (local or in domain). [Microsoft explain how to use it in C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675899.aspx). [This](http://www.csharpfr.com//code.aspx?ID=52023) french site give a project where the same thing is done in C#. I also do my own version.