# Get all folders from network

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming

I'm kind of lost, I have a task to get all folders from a network domain,
E.g. (My Network Places/Entire Network/Microsoft Windows Network/xyNetwork).

I have to get all folders and sub-folders then get all security groups assigned to this folder and the rights granted to each security group.

The second part I have done before, however, the first part which is getting a list of all folders seems to be very complicated.

Any guides or references that might help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [List all computers in active directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605567/list-all-computers-in-active-directory)

Comment: Not clear and way to broad.  Start the first specific problem and what have you tired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is a code in another similar entry that lists all the computer names from the network... That's the first part of your requirement. For the second part I think you need to dig into `System.DirectoryServices` classes since there are some for permissions as well... good luck.

```
//Lists all available computer names on the network.
public static List<String> ListNetworkComputers()
{
    var computerNames = new List<String>();
    var computerSchema = "Computer";

    var entries = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry("WinNT:");
    foreach (var domains in entries.Children)
    {
        foreach (var computer in domains.Children)
        {
            if (computer.SchemaClassName.ToLower().Contains(computerSchema .ToLower()))
            {
                computerNames.Add(computer.Name);
            }
        }
    }

    return computerNames;
}
```

I just printed out the values and it worked fine for me.

```
foreach (string lst in ListNetworkComputers())
{
    Console.WriteLine("PC: " + lst);
}
```

(Above code taken from: [Getting computer names from my network places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236249/getting-computer-names-from-my-network-places) )

What you need is to access the Win32_Share WMI from your code.
Add the reference to System.Management.dll and use the following code.

code example in VB.NET from the topic here: 
http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/finding-share-s-directory-spec-t3064222.html

C# version of the VB.net program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var objClass = new System.Management.ManagementClass("Win32_Share");

        foreach(var objShare in objClass.GetInstances())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} -> {1}", 
                objShare.Properties["Name"].Value, objShare.Properties["Path"].Value));
        }
    }
}
```

You can compare the results of the code above against the result that you get by running the following command in a windows command prompt:

`C:\net share`

Which will give you the Share Name (shared name given when sharing i.e. MySharedDir) and the Resource (windows path i.e. C:\myshareddir).

Comment: It seems that i'm not making my self clear. What i want is the following. open My network places, then microsoft windows network then you should see alot of network domain, select one of them which contain thousands of PC , servers .. etc (then for each one i want to get the list of folders and sub folders)

Comment: @Maro - What about the link to the Active Directory question?  Does that answer your question?

Comment: @Maro, you are welcome. a broadcast to get all computers on the network is time consuming by nature... why not adding a "This will take some time. Please wait." message and scrollbar? hehe

Comment: It's not an application that will be used by users to display a message, it's an application that will run every night to get data from all servers in the company

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use [`GetDirectories`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). For example:

```
var folders = Directory.GetDirectories(@"\\server\share");
```

to get all directories (i.e. include subdirectories), use the following:

```
var folders = Directory.GetDirectories(@"\\server\share", "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
```

Comment: It's not getting a directory from a server, it's getting all workstation that are in a network then get all directories of these work station