# C# get a list of computers that a user has access to in a domain

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am writing a C# winform and trying to get a list of computers in a domain from one user account using active Directory (AD) but I can't seem to figure it out.

Any guidance or samples would be much appreciated. 
Thanks
JPL

Comment: You need to be more clear about what you are trying to do.  The title implies one thing (computers that a user has access to) and the question states another (list of computer from one user account).  I don't know about other readers, but I can't tell what you are trying to do.  Also, you're more likely to get help if you post some code that demonstrates that you've made some effort.  Your code might also help us understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: view this topic : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605567/list-all-computers-in-active-directory

Comment: Thanks for response, Tony.  Like I said in my message,  I would like to have a list of computers within a domain which a specific user account has access to.   I can get a list of all computers within that domain but the list is large (3000+ computers) then traverse down to each comp to check for that user account access would is bad idea.   

I don't need a super details on writing codes, I just need some guidance, logic, algorithm or just what functions....   

Once again, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The only way AD can enforce this is with the list of machines a user is allowed to logon to, which is an attribute of the user, not the computer. It's a legacy feature and probably not what you're expecting.

In practice, computers define who can logon to them based on a number of security rights, e.g. Allow Logon Locally, Allow Logon via Remote Desktop, etc. You would need to query each computer to find out what users/groups are in those rights, and then compare that to the user's token to see if there's a match.