# List only client computer objects in AD

Tags: c#

I want to get all client-only computer objects from AD, I mean, Windows Clients machines. I am using the sample code from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605567/list-all-computers-in-active-directory), but I would like to know how I can filter servers out.

Here's my code:

```
class Program
    {
        public static List<string> GetComputers()
        {
            List<string> ComputerNames = new List<string>();

            DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://neuventus.local");
            DirectorySearcher mySearcher = new DirectorySearcher(dirEntry);
            mySearcher.Filter = ("(objectClass=computer)");
            mySearcher.SizeLimit = int.MaxValue;
            mySearcher.PageSize = int.MaxValue;

            foreach (SearchResult resEnt in mySearcher.FindAll())
            {

                string ComputerName = resEnt.GetDirectoryEntry().Name;
                if (ComputerName.StartsWith("CN="))
                    ComputerName = ComputerName.Remove(0, "CN=".Length);
                ComputerNames.Add(ComputerName);
            }

            mySearcher.Dispose();
            dirEntry.Dispose();

            return ComputerNames;
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> newList = GetComputers();

            newList.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("C:\\SavedLists.txt", newList);


        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You could filter on the `operatingSystem` attribute maybe? Are your client computers and servers in a common OU? Could you just not search in the OU your servers live in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding an `operatingSystem` condition to your filter.

`mySearcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=computer)(!(operatingSystem=*server*)))";`

Note that this will only work if the all your servers are running a server operating system with `server` in the name. Also assume that no client machines run a server operating system.

Comment: But I want to get all clients only. That would be *client*?

Comment: It would be all objects that the `operatingSystem` property does not contain `server`. To my knowledge that would be a client unless you have a different definition in mind.

Comment: @ivcubr I think your syntax might be slightly wrong. E.g. your quotes and a missing `&` operator.

Comment: @itsme86 thanks, I believe the edited sample is correct. I don't have access to my lab at the moment to verify though

Comment: @ivcubr, thank you so much, it worked. I need to add also the `sAMAccountName`, but no idea what value I should add. Do I have to create another question?

Comment: @SergioCalderon NP, typically it is best to create separate questions so that issues are isolated to separate questions. Since it sounds like you need more information about what the `sAMAccountName` property, I'd recommend opening a new question. If you do, @me the link in this question as a related one and I can take a look in the next several hours