# How to get the objectguid and objectsid of Computer in AD using c#

Tags: c#

based on [List all computers in active directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605567/list-all-computers-in-active-directory)

im Trying to get the objectGUID and objectSID of a computer in my ad domain.

So I added

```
                mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("objectGUID");
                mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("objectSID");
```

and try to receive the informations with:

```
                            string computerGUID = (string)resEnt.Properties["objectGUID"][0].ToString();
                            string computerSID = (string)resEnt.Properties["objectSID"][0].ToString();
```

but just getting 'System.Byte[]' back. How can I get the "real" data?

thank you

Comment: Note that you don't need to cast string when you are using `ToString();`

Comment: It seems you are getting a byte array. You can give a try to `string computerGUID = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resEnt.Properties["objectGUID"][0], 0, resEnt.Properties["objectGUID"][0].length)`

Comment: Look this : https://philippsen.wordpress.com/2010/12/07/retrieving-user-sid-using-directoryentry-and-directorysearcher/

It is for User but the logic is the same I think..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you apply the filter, you use `FindOne()` that retrieves the first entry based on the filter

```
mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("objectGUID");
mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("objectSID");
SearchResult searchResult = mySearcher.FindOne(); //FindAll() can return a collection

var objectGUID = searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["objectGUID"].Value;

var computerGUID = searchResult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["objectSID"].Value;
```

**OR**

```
 mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("objectGUID");
 mySearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("objectSID");

 SearchResultCollection results;

 results = mySearcher.FindAll();

string sidStringValue="";
string guidStringValue="";

    foreach (var result in results)
    {

                  //reset SID

                  byte[] SID = null;

                  if (result.Properties[“objectSid”].Count > 0)

                  {

                      SID = (byte[]) result.Properties[“objectSid”][0];

                  }

                  sidStringValue = GetSidString(SID); 

             }//
```

**GetSidString** *Is a part of Unmanaged code so you'll have to P/Invoke*

```
[DllImport(“advapi32”, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]

static extern bool ConvertSidToStringSid([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] byte[] pSID, out IntPtr ptrSid);


public static string GetSidString(byte[] sid)
{

            IntPtr ptrSid;

            string sidString;

            if (!ConvertSidToStringSid(sid, out ptrSid))

                throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception();

            try

            {

                sidString = Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(ptrSid);

            }

            finally

            {

                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptrSid);

            }

            return sidString;

}
```

**Note** :

Second approach emphasizes on `objectSid` you'll have to modify it accordingly for `objectGUID`

**References:**

https://philippsen.wordpress.com/2010/12/07/retrieving-user-sid-using-directoryentry-and-directorysearcher/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using running the following PowerShell commands from C#:

Get-ADUser USERNAME -Properties * | Select SamaccountName,ObjectSid,ObjectGUID

Comment: I need the properties from the ad computer and I cant use powershell because I write an app with c#